# aws cli query and output table format with named column

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I just want to list EC2 with a table output format with a name for my column. But when I add the query to avoid to get EC2 from Auto Scaling Group, I got an error...

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone}' --profile dev --output table
-------------------
|DescribeInstances|
+-----------------+
|       AZ        |
+-----------------+
|  eu-west-3a     |
|  eu-west-3a     |
|  eu-west-3a     |
...
```

OK

And there :

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?!contains(Tags[].Key, `aws:autoscaling:groupName`)].{AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone}' --profile dev --output table

Row should have 1 elements, instead it has 0
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question? Do you simply want to remove the top row showing `DescribeInstances`?

Comment: when I want to filter, I don't have any instances. I don't understand the error : Row should have 1 elements, instead it has 0. I have a lot of EC2 without autoscaling tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, JMESPATH can be weird sometimes. Try:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?!contains(Tags[].Key, `aws:autoscaling:groupName`)]|[].{AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone}' --profile dev --output table
```

(If it works, don't ask me why.)